# Changing names of every dataframe in a list

Tags: r, list, replace, gsub, names

I have created a list (called raw.lst) containing 36 excel dataframes. Each has .xlsx at the end of each dataframe name for example:

```
[1] "18_05_01.xlsx" "18_05_02.xlsx" "18_05_03.xlsx" "18_05_04.xlsx" "18_05_05.xlsx"
```

I would like to remove the .xlsx from each DF in the list so they look like this for example:

```
[1] "18_05_01" "18_05_02" "18_05_03" "18_05_04" "18_05_05"
```

I have tried the following without any success:

```
map(raw.lst, ~  .x %>% 
                  rename_all(~ gsub(pattern = ".xlsx", replacement = "")))
```

AND

```
lapply(raw.lst, function(x) setNames(x, sub("^[^.xlsx]*_", "", names(x))))
```

AND

```
lapply(raw.lst, sub, pattern = "[.xlsx]", replacement = "")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to rename the list elements like: `names(raw.lst) <- gsub(".xlsx", "", names(raw.lst))`? Or are you trying to remove the suffix from column names within list elements?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).